# How can I have an abstract method that accepts an argument of type "my type"?

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

Let's say I have an abstract class Animal with an abstract method

```
public abstract Animal mateWith(Animal mate);
```

the problem is, if I create subclasses Snake and Armadillo, a call like this would then be legal:

```
mySnake.mateWith(myArmadillo);
```

But I only want snakes to be able to mate with snakes. I need to be able to define something like this:

```
public abstract Animal_Of_My_Class mateWith(Animal_Of_My_Class mate);
```

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: In C++ you could use RTTI (`dynamic_cast`) which is kinda "anti-polymorphism".

Comment: "I only want snakes to be able to mate with snakes." come on, give love a chance.

Comment: @Kayaman indeed. This design wouldn't allow you to model, say, a Lion mating with a Lion and [a Lion mating with a Tiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liger).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Self-bounded generics to the rescue:

```
abstract class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> {
  abstract T mateWith(T mate);
}
```

then:

```
class Animal_Of_My_Class extends Animal<Animal_Of_My_Class> {
  Animal_Of_My_Class mateWith(Animal_Of_My_Class mate) { ... }
}
```

Note that you can't constrain `T` to be the implementing class (as in, you can't require that `Animal_Of_My_Class extends Animal<Animal_Of_My_Class>` rather than `Animal_Of_My_Class extends Animal<Another_Animal_Of_My_Class>`).

Comment: So is this kind of thing commonly done, or discouraged? I'm worried I might be over-engineering.

Comment: What kind of thing? Self bounded generics? They crop up here and there, e.g. in abstract builders.

Comment: Using this pattern in order to implement a method that accepts only arguments of "my type". The complexity of that declaration has me wondering if maybe I just shouldn't be trying to do that in the first place.